# Chrome Profiles - Compiled code loaded several times into memory after a couple of page reloads

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, memory-leaks, virtual-machine, v8

While looking for a memory leak (finally fixed it) noticed that my web app's source: `bundle.js` (bundled via rollup), after several page reloads appears to be loaded multiple times into memory under the *constructor* pane, `(compiled code)` row:

[image]

I have double checked everything, even gutted the app to be sure, but the source still appears multiple times after a couple of page reloads.

Thanks.

Comment: Does your server serve a http 304 - file not modified?

Comment: @Jonas Willms http://127.0.0.1:3333/js/bundle.js - has the Status Code: 304 Not Modified.